# Another ways to ask "What is her name?"

Tags: sentence-structure

What are another ways to ask "what is her name"?

Can I ask What is she named or something like that?

Comment: There are tons of other options, each less common than the last... the fact is that anything other than "what is her name" is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the best way to ask it - "What is her name?"

But if you want to know her name and throw in some creative and indirect approaches there are various ways:

> "Does she have a nickname?" (if she has, what is it? Though this is somehow assertive in my opinion)
>
> "Oh, she's my (classmate, friend's friend, neighbor), do you know her name?" (at least this gives some basis to curiosity)

There are so many ways. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some expressions very similar, but not quite the same, to what is her name would be

> What does she go by?
>
> What is she called?

Comment: I've never heard a native speaker use the phrase "How is she called"... unless perhaps talking about a non-human creature, like a dog.

Comment: Well, maybe a nickname.

Comment: Nope. We don't use "how" with asking for a person's name... at least not in AmE. "What is she called?"... maybe. "How is she called?"... no. Even "What does she go by?" implies that you're asking for the person's nickname or shortened version of their name... "Her name is Sandra but she goes by Sandy." That being said, it is a very common issue I believe, amongst non-native speakers.

Comment: Or her/his position --- Mr.President.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that. Not sure how "her position" applies.. and a female would never be called "Mr" anything.

Comment: This question addresses this issue very well: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/how-is-this-called-vs-what-is-this-called?rq=1

Comment: I don't know why I never knew it. I guess I thought it that way since my language works like that. Still feels kind of strange to me, though.