# On the usage of 'to call'

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

I cannot recall where exactly but in a book that discussed some common mistakes in English I got to read about why the sentence **What is it called in English?** is purely (or at least highly) ungrammatical. In LDOCE 5th edition, there is the following entry:

[image: the entry of the verb 'to call' in LDOCE 5th edition]

In this sense, the above-mentioned sentence is correct (?) but these alternatives were offered if one is to ask such a question:

> **What is *друг* in English?** (friend)
>
> **What is the English equivalent for *Liebeskummer*?** (pangs of love)
>
> **How do you say *un mirroir* in English?** (a mirror)

Does that question really sound that outlandish or is the author being the grammar police?

(The book also mentions that if I am holding or pointing to an object, I can ask **What is this called in English?** but I have never asked it, to be honest.)

Comment: You can certainly indicate something (e.g. a picture or an object) or describe it, and ask "What is this (or that) called in English?". Entirely grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: *What is this called in English?* is okay, but *How is this called in English?* isn't used in that sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["How is this called" vs "What is this called"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/how-is-this-called-vs-what-is-this-called)